# Configuration file for Virtual Console

Tags: linux, bash, console

Does any configuration file exist for virtual console, when a user logins in it which is read and executed ?

My requirement: To execute some shell commands when a user logins using the virtual console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the configuration in `~/.bash_profile` works. Another option is putting the configuration in `~/.profile`, but this file will be ignored if `~/.bash_profile` file already exists in the filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

If any user logs in using `bash`, the commands in `/etc/profile` are executed. There you can check if the login was from a virtual console (and not from a terminal after logging in the GUI) and take action based on that.

You can e.g test on `$TERM` equalling `linux`, or on not having `$WINDOWID`.

If you need this only for some users, you can put the actions in their `~/.bash_login` as well, but you would have to trust them not to change that part of that file after logging in. With `/etc/profile` you don't normally have that problem (and if the user has root access there is little you can do anyway). But you can have the action check for the `id` of the user logging in and take action or not based on that.